# Outlook mail : option to change mail subject color using vsto

Tags: vsto, outlook-addin

I have couple of doubts regarding Outlook addIns.

1. I created a ribbon for Outlook application using VSTO.
   While sending the mail i call some API and make some db entries.
   I keep the mail in inbox even after i sent the mail.
   Now i need an option to change the color of that message subject (like indication this is already send. eg : unread mail subject is in bold )
   Is there any way that i can achieve this ?
2. The ribbon i created is showing under Add-ins menu.
   i wated to show this in Home itself.
   I tried tab idMso="TabHome", TabMail etc but its not working (i am using office 2010)

Comment: Hii In case if anyone facing this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to modify the view setting based on some condition - look at an existing Outlook views that bold the unread messages and display overdue messages in red.

[image]

Comment: Hi Dimitry , actually i am trying to do using programmatically. I created ribbon using VSTO

Comment: You will need to modify the folder view use MAPIFolder.CurrentView and View.AutoFormatRules.

Comment: Hi Dimitry, i tried few options but didn't work. So i went to add category. I added a category to the mail so user will know this mail already sent. Also i created a new VSTO project and tried tabMail then it showed in homepage itself. i don't what went wrong in my original application. thank for your support.